# What function is triggered after popping to a previous view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I'm writing and iOS application in Swift. I use the below code to pop back to a previous view controller. I then want the data in my previous view controller to reload. I assumed the ViewDidAppear funtion would be triggered however it isn't running the code within the function.

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Any ideas on how I could get code to run on my previous view after popping back to it?

Comment: `viewDidAppear` should be called when popping back from another vc in the stack

Comment: Also `viewWillAppear` will be called before `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assume this scenario, If you have a controller first and second. you are pushing controller second from  first. So on calling popViewControllerAnimated in controller second then controller first `viewWillAppear` will be called then `viewDidAppear` is called

**viewWillAppear:animated** for controller first will be called

Comment: Hi, for some reason it didn't appear to being called before. However, I've thrown in some test prints and it now appears to be calling it. The code I was trying to run may have been incorrect

Comment: It's working now. I was calling reload data, without actually loading the data from my stored procedure again

Comment: This appears to no longer be the case for iOS 13. Is there another way other than setting up a protocol/delegate?

Answer (score 1):

Both -(void)viewWillAppear and -(void)viewDidAppear should be called.